# Current state of Azure App Services

Tags: azure

As far as I know Azure App Services consisted of

- Web Apps
- Mobile Apps
- API Apps
- Logic Apps
- Function Apps

However official site documentation [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/) leads directly to Web Apps Documentation. So my question is what is currently part of Azure App Services ? Are Logic Apps and Function Apps their own category now ?

Because so far it seems that Azure App Services consist of Web Apps, Mobile Apps, API Apps and Web Apps for Containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Logic App** and **Function App** are also be consisted of **Azure App Service**, you could refer to the screenshot. Also, you could find we should create a **Function App** via **App Service** in the portal.

[image]

Comment: This seems to be useful resource. But where are Mobile Apps ? So in general  Azure App services consists of WebApps, Mobile Apps, Functions Apps, Logic Apps, API Apps, WebApps for Containers ?

Comment: @Nashmár Yes, this is the link of the [screenshot](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/app-service/), you could find `Quickly and easily build web and mobile apps for any platform or device with Azure App Service.` in it.

Comment: I was just confused it is not presented there as app type like the others. I just couldn´t find up to date resource, what really is and is not part of App Services. Anway thanks for answer